FutureWarning in emobpy: incompatible dtype assignment with Pandas DataFrame
I am using the emobpy library to set custom rules for a mobility analysis, but I encounter a FutureWarning about incompatible data types when trying to modify DataFrame items. Here's the problematic code snippet:
m.set_rules(rule_key="user_defined")

The warning message is as follows:

FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '[[list of values]]' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
df.loc[:, j] = df[j].apply(make_list, factor=factor)

Any idea on how I can solve this issue?
Upgrading libraries: I ensured that all related libraries, including pandas and emobpy, are up to date to avoid any deprecated behavior.

How to make good reproducible pandas examples, and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. For example we dont know what m is
